# What is the best way to Insert a dynamic number of rows into SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm using C# and ADO.NET to insert a dynamic number of rows into a SQL Server table, 
but I'm not sure if it's the best approach or the most efficient.

After reading different opinions, I used this way but wanted to confirm if this is a good idea.

The tools used can be changed if you say it's better

```
SqlConnection sc = DBManager.CreateConnection();
sc.Open();

foreach (string item in listSurfaceTypes)
{
    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.surface_type_inspection " +
                "(InspectionID, SurfaceType) VALUES (@InspecId, @SurfaceType)", sc);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InspecId", id);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurfaceType", item);

    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

sc.Close();
```

Oh and by the way there is more than one table so I have to iterate multiple times, should I open and close the connection for every table or use the same connection for all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a minimum batch the inserts in a SqlTransaction, and put the SqlConnection in a `using` block.  The transaction ensures that the rows are either all inserted or none are, and improves performance by eliminating the commit and log flush after each row.

```
using (var sc = DBManager.CreateConnection())
{
    sc.Open();
    var tran = sc.BeginTransaction();
    foreach (string item in listSurfaceTypes)
    {
        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.surface_type_inspection (InspectionID,SurfaceType) values(@InspecId,@SurfaceType)", sc);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InspecId", id);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurfaceType", item);

        insert.Transaction = tran;
        insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    tran.Commit();
    sc.Close();
}
```

SqlBulkCopy will be significantly faster if you have thousands of rows to insert.

Comment: Also, one could remove the creation of the `SqlCommand` and the parameters to outside the foreach loop, and just keep settiing the parameter values inside the loop

Comment: `.AddWithValue` ? Argh! See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Comment: Isn't a connection.Close rather redundant when you have a using block?

Comment: What about a using block for the Command. After all, it exposes a `.Dispose` method.

Comment: SqlCommand doesn’t actually need to be Dispose()d.  It inherits IDisposable from Component, but doesn’t do anything.  Closing the SqlConnection cleans up everything related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use SqlBulkCopy class, this way you don't do a row by row insert which is much slower. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy